# full unix username of a user

Tags: python, unix

Wondering if you know if there is a slick way to get full username from shell?

> example: if my unix username is froyo then I want to get my full name
>   as registered in the system in this case [froyo  === Abhishek Pratap]

finger command does it but for all the logged in users at the same time ..so that needs some parsing to get the right value. Anything slicker ?

Anything from inside python would be great too.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using `pwd.getpwuid` and `os.getuid`:

```
>>> import os
>>> import pwd
>>> pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[4]
```

This is the traditional Unix way of doing it (based on standard C library calls).

Comment: awesome this works ...I knew python would have something straight forward.

Comment: This is not Python as such. It is the standard Unix C library which provides the `getpwuid` and `getuid` functions. These are simply exposed in the Python `os` and `pwd` modules.

Comment: ur right ..for me I wanted to get the answer in python env for downstream usage so this works perfect even though we may say it has no python flavor to it :)

Comment: The GECOS field can contain comma-separated list of values on some systems, so you may want to add an extra `.split()` for that.

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian will return the Full USERNAME, with 4 commas, sometimes intertwined with data.  To subvert this, use:  pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[4].split(',')[0]